# Scaling data in the axis

Tags: pgfplots

I'm new in tikz and I'm trying to convert a plot from python. I'm using matplotlib2tikz and everything was ok until I see the scale in x axis.

[image]

This is the image in Python

[image]

And this is the image in Tikz

I don't know why the values are scaled by 10^4. Can someone help me with this?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} %inclusion de figures
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}

\begin{axis}[
title={Altitude vs Carbon Monoxide},
ylabel={CO [ppm]},
xmin=0, xmax=24731.58,
ymin=39.035, ymax=44.205,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
xmajorgrids,
x grid style={lightgray!92.02614379084967!black},
ymajorgrids,
y grid style={lightgray!92.02614379084967!black}
]
\addplot [semithick, color0, forget plot]
table {%
208.8 43.97
197.7 43.97
201 43.97
205 43.74
208.2 43.74
209.8 43.74
211.6 43.74
220.6 43.52
225.1 43.52
226.3 43.52
229.6 43.52
234.6 43.3
238.3 43.3
239.9 43.52
243.5 43.3
247.2 43.3
250.2 43.52
254 43.3
257.1 43.3
262.8 43.3
268.3 43.3
268.6 43.3
272.1 43.3
276.8 43.3
285.8 43.3
287.3 43.3
291 43.08
297.6 43.08
305.4 43.3
308.3 43.3
313.2 43.3
316.9 43.3
328.6 43.08
336.3 43.08
344.1 43.08
352.6 43.08
360.7 43.08
368.9 43.08
372.5 43.08
377.4 43.08
385.3 43.08
409.4 43.08
416.7 43.08
424.8 43.08
427.3 43.08
439.5 43.08
444.4 43.08
450.6 43.08
457.3 43.08
471 43.08
473.9 43.08
477.4 43.08
482.6 42.87
491.2 43.08
493.5 43.08
497.4 43.08
501.8 43.08
507.5 43.08
517.1 42.87
523.6 42.87
527.4 42.87
531.7 43.08
538.2 42.87
543.4 43.08
548.6 42.87
554 42.87
561.5 43.08
567.1 42.87
569.4 42.87
574.6 42.87
583.6 42.87
587.7 42.87
592.5 42.87
594.3 43.08
599.9 42.87
611.6 42.87
617.3 42.87
620.4 42.87
625.6 42.87
634.8 42.87
638.6 42.87
645.8 42.87
648.1 42.87
657.7 42.87
664.3 42.87
671.8 42.87
674.4 42.87
684.3 42.87
688.6 42.87
695 42.87
702.6 42.87
710.9 42.87
717.1 42.87
722.8 42.87
728.9 42.87
735.5 42.87
743.9 42.87
747.2 42.87
753.1 42.87
759 42.87
768.7 42.87
770.4 42.87
775.3 42.87
780.5 42.87
788.8 42.65
795 42.87
801.1 42.87
804.5 42.87
832.9 42.87
1276.6 42.87
1038 42.87
1072.7 42.65
1197.1 42.65
1403.7 42.87
1488.2 42.65
1627.8 42.65
1695.1 42.65
1709.8 42.65
1715 42.65
1721.5 42.65
1728 42.65
1739.7 42.65
1745.1 42.65
1753.1 42.65
1757.1 42.65
1763.3 42.65
1794.8 42.65
1798.3 42.65
1802.5 42.65
1805.9 42.87
1811.1 42.65
1816 42.65
1821.2 42.65
1825.6 42.65
1839.5 42.65
1845.9 42.65
1852.5 42.65
1857.5 42.65
1868.3 42.65
1872 42.43
1878.3 42.65
1884.9 42.65
1894.3 42.65
1904.6 42.65
1911.9 42.65
1915.7 42.65
1922.2 42.65
1931.2 42.65
1938 42.65
1944.7 42.65
1952.4 42.65
1961 42.65
1967.7 42.65
1972.4 42.65
1979.5 42.65
1985.6 42.65
1992.1 42.43
1997.7 42.43
2003.3 42.43
2011.2 42.65
2018.8 42.43
2025.5 42.43
2032.5 42.43
2040.2 42.43
2046.4 42.43
2051 42.43
2057.3 42.43
2063.5 42.43
2069.8 42.43
2077 42.43
2082.1 42.43
2088.9 42.43
2094.1 42.43
2103.1 42.43
2105.4 42.43
2112.5 42.43
2120 42.43
2131.4 42.43
2135.2 42.43
2138.9 42.43
2142.6 42.43
2150.2 42.43
2159.9 42.43
2164.7 42.43
2170.5 42.43
2178.8 42.43
2188.4 42.43
2195.9 42.43
2203.5 42.43
2213.2 42.43
2215.3 42.43
2224.9 42.43
2227.4 42.43
2231.2 42.43
2237.4 42.43
2247.1 42.43
2254.5 42.43
2263 42.43
2271.6 42.43
2281.1 42.43
2287.8 42.43
2292.7 42.43
2313.9 42.43
2556.4 42.43
2578.3 42.43
2626.9 42.43
2699.5 42.43
2839.9 42.43
2934.6 42.43
2977.3 42.43
3001.8 42.43
3066.4 42.43
3118.2 42.43
3138.5 42.43
3172.1 42.43
3194.9 42.43
3216.3 42.43
3237.7 42.43
3254.7 42.43
3274.5 42.43
3303.4 42.43
3325.1 42.43
3349.2 42.43
3363.9 42.43
3376.7 42.43
3404.4 42.43
3418.4 42.43
3428 42.43
3438.6 42.43
3461.6 42.43
3471.1 42.43
3485.2 42.43
3498.2 42.43
3517.9 42.43
3531.1 42.43
3544 42.43
3556.6 42.43
3568.3 42.43
3579.5 42.21
3581.6 42.43
3586.4 42.43
3588.4 42.43
3595.8 42.21
3599.7 42.43
3606.1 42.21
3609.4 42.21
3617.4 42.21
3619.6 42.21
3621.2 42.21
3625.3 42.21
3628.6 42.43
3633.5 42.43
3637.4 42.43
3641.2 42.21
3645.6 42.43
3655.8 42.21
3656.8 42.21
3662.1 42.21
3667 42.21
3675.2 42.21
3676.6 42.21
3681 42.43
3686.3 42.21
3688.7 42.21
3695.8 42.21
3698.9 42.21
3702.8 42.21
3706.9 42.21
3715.3 42.21
3716.6 42.21
3720.9 42.21
3725.7 42.21
3729.3 42.21
3736.4 42.21
3742.2 42.21
3748.9 42.21
3751.2 42.21
3754.9 42.21
3759.5 42.21
3765.3 42.21
3770.8 42.21
3775.9 42.21
3781.6 42.21
3789.6 42.21
3792.9 42.21
3798.1 42.21
3803.5 42.21
3809.1 42.21
3814.3 42.21
3818.8 42.21
3823.7 42.21
3833.8 42.21
3838 42.21
3843.3 42.21
3845.8 42.21
3855.3 42.21
3857.6 42.21
3862.6 42.21
3863.1 42.21
3870.8 42.21
3876.8 42.21
3880.8 42.21
3887.8 42.21
3889.6 42.21
3894 42.21
3899.5 42.21
3661.4 42.21
4042.8 42.21
4183.3 42.21
4315.7 42.21
4402.2 42.21
4458 42.21
4518.8 42.21
4607.5 42.21
4648.6 42.21
4666 42.21
4705.3 42.21
4739.2 42.21
4765.4 42.21
4791.2 42.21
4808.2 42.21
4822.1 42.21
4855.6 42
4858 42
4861.7 42.21
4866.2 42
4866.8 42
4867.9 42
4871.8 42
4875.8 42
4880.5 42
4883.3 42
4891.2 42
4890.6 42
4897.9 42
4898.8 42
4909 42
4910.5 42
4918.2 42
4917.3 42
4921.1 42
4928.2 42
4930.5 42
4932.4 42
4937 42
4948.6 42
4950 42
4951 42
4958.3 42
4961.4 42
4969.1 42
4972.4 42
4978.5 42
4981.8 42
4995.2 42
4996.7 42
5007.4 42
5009.3 42
5022.2 42
5025.7 42
5027 42
5034.7 42
5035.3 42
5041.5 42
5049 42
5047 42
5054.6 42
5060.9 42
5064.9 42
5071.2 42
5078 42
5081.7 42
5089.6 42
5098.1 42
5101.9 42
5108.8 42
5113.9 42
5123.5 42
5126.9 42
5135.3 42
5135.3 42
5143.8 42
5150.2 42
5158.4 42
5221.5 42
5233.1 42
5244.9 42
5248.1 42
5253.7 42
5817.7 42
5539.4 42
5564.8 42
5601.9 42
5638.2 42
5676.1 42
5705.7 42
5717.4 42
5726.8 42
5738.4 42
5742.9 42
5750.3 42
5757.1 42
5763.6 42
5773.7 42
5780.3 42
5784.1 42
5790.4 42
5825.7 42
5831.9 42
5828.1 42
5831.1 42
5837.7 42
5845.7 42
5852.2 42
5859.9 42
5863.1 42
5870.6 42
5878.9 42
5885.8 42
5888.3 42
5891.6 42
5906.1 42
5908.9 42
5920.8 42
5924.9 42
5935 42
5938.9 42
5948.4 42
5952.7 42
5956 41.79
5966.9 42
5970.1 42
5976.5 41.79
5984.8 41.79
5998.9 42
6007.9 41.79
6016.7 41.79
6018.1 41.79
6067.9 41.79
6085.4 41.79
6094.8 42
6099 41.79
6103.1 41.79
6119.4 42
6126.6 42
6135.7 42
6140.9 42
6150.9 42
6155.5 42
6163.9 42
6175.5 42
6300 42
6316.1 42
6337.2 42
6355.4 42
6375.1 41.79
6399.2 41.79
6426.3 42
6451.9 42
6474 41.79
6491.7 42
6527.9 42
6554 42
6575.3 42
6596.8 42
6615.7 41.79
6644.8 41.79
6649.2 41.79
6664 41.79
6680 41.79
6711.4 42
6719.6 42
6732.5 42
6756.4 42
6787.6 41.79
6793.5 41.79
6799.5 42
6810.6 41.79
6821 41.79
6854.6 41.79
6873 41.79
6887.5 41.79
6900.7 41.79
6913.9 41.79
6930.2 41.79
6940.4 41.79
6952.9 41.79
6971.8 41.79
6993.1 41.79
7013.2 41.79
7025.5 41.79
7046.3 41.79
7063.6 41.79
7080.5 41.79
7096.7 41.79
7105.9 41.79
7121 41.79
7142.7 41.79
7151.2 41.79
7168.2 41.79
7179.9 41.79
7193.3 41.79
7213.6 41.79
7221.7 41.79
7233.4 41.79
7248.6 41.79
7255.2 41.79
7258.7 41.79
7267.6 41.79
7287.6 41.79
7297.8 41.79
7317.5 41.79
7331.4 41.79
7348.5 41.79
7356.3 41.79
7367.4 41.79
7385.4 41.79
7392.3 41.79
7407.2 41.79
7420.9 41.79
7426 41.79
7441.5 41.79
7449.9 41.79
7462.4 41.79
7474.2 41.79
7488.8 41.79
7497.4 41.79
7504.9 41.79
7974.8 41.79
8169.8 41.79
8210.9 41.79
8253.1 41.79
8290.8 41.79
8326.6 41.79
8360.9 41.79
8393.4 41.79
8435.6 41.79
8485.3 41.79
8510.5 41.79
8532.8 41.79
8553.2 41.79
8584.4 41.79
8613.8 41.79
8633.3 41.79
8658.5 41.79
8684.6 41.79
8741.8 41.79
8780.5 41.79
8804.8 41.79
8832.9 41.79
8860.7 41.79
8873.1 41.79
8886.4 41.79
8902.6 41.79
8918.9 41.79
8934.9 41.79
8947.9 41.79
8966.4 41.79
8972.2 41.79
8997.2 41.79
9003.7 41.79
9022.4 41.79
9028.9 41.79
9044.1 41.79
9061.7 41.79
9076.8 41.79
9083.5 41.79
9090.5 41.79
9112 41.79
9123.3 41.79
9139.6 41.79
9146.7 41.79
9163.2 41.79
9182.4 41.79
9201.4 41.79
9208.9 41.79
9223 41.79
9239.4 41.79
9254.1 41.79
9274.6 41.79
9293.8 41.79
9310.3 41.79
9323.6 41.79
9341.4 41.79
9348.7 41.79
9365.6 41.79
9393.8 41.79
9413.5 41.79
9423.9 41.79
9431.6 41.79
9439.2 41.79
9452.4 41.79
9466 41.79
9480.9 41.79
9496.9 41.79
9510.8 41.79
9524.9 41.79
9542.8 41.79
9563.8 41.79
9565.7 41.79
9591 41.79
9610.5 41.79
9628.8 41.79
9633.9 41.79
9659.4 41.79
9678.2 41.79
9686.4 41.79
9695.4 41.79
9704.4 41.79
9718.1 41.79
9733.3 41.79
9748.5 41.79
9756.3 41.79
9776.9 41.79
9783 41.79
9798 41.79
9803.8 41.79
9818 41.57
9827.2 41.79
9836.6 41.79
9845.2 41.79
9855.4 41.79
9875.5 41.79
9885.3 41.79
9894.6 41.79
9901.6 41.79
9914.4 41.79
9928.9 41.79
9936.1 41.79
9947.2 41.79
9953.6 41.57
9965.4 41.57
9976.7 41.57
9989.8 41.57
10002.3 41.57
10005.8 41.57
10012 41.57
10018.8 41.57
10026.9 41.57
10032.5 41.57
10041.4 41.57
10048.3 41.57
10052 41.57
10061.9 41.57
10074.5 41.57
10108 41.57
10113.3 41.57
10117.6 41.57
10123.9 41.57
10143.1 41.79
10147 41.79
10161 41.57
10165.8 41.57
10177.2 41.57
10186.4 41.79
10193.1 41.79
10202.6 41.57
10209.7 41.57
10225.5 41.57
10231 41.79
10236.8 41.57
10244.6 41.57
10250.9 41.79
10258.1 41.79
10262.8 41.79
10270.3 41.79
10276.8 41.57
10285.5 41.57
10289.2 41.57
10294.5 41.57
10300.6 41.57
10305.6 41.57
10311.5 41.57
10317.4 41.57
10325.4 41.79
10332.4 41.57
10339.6 41.57
10343.6 41.57
10353.5 41.57
10366.4 41.57
10377.1 41.57
10383.2 41.57
10394.1 41.57
10399.6 41.57
10404.7 41.57
10415.8 41.57
10421.8 41.57
10428.4 41.57
10433.4 41.57
10438.8 41.57
10444.5 41.57
10451.8 41.57
10459.5 41.57
10468.4 41.57
10476.5 41.57
10482.2 41.57
10488.3 41.57
10491.8 41.57
10499.3 41.57
10510.4 41.57
10517.5 41.57
10522.1 41.57
10534.1 41.57
10537.2 41.57
10541.9 41.57
10556.3 41.57
10566.6 41.57
10606.9 41.57
10620.6 41.57
10627.8 41.57
10637.8 41.57
10642.4 41.57
10650.4 41.57
10659.4 41.57
10662.6 41.57
10673.9 41.57
10694.4 41.57
10707.7 41.57
10705.9 41.57
10714.8 41.57
10720.6 41.57
10728.4 41.57
10734.6 41.57
10742.4 41.57
10744 41.57
10754.9 41.57
10758.1 41.57
10761.5 41.57
10768 41.57
10773.1 41.57
10784 41.57
10792.2 41.57
10796.9 41.57
10805.4 41.57
10817.4 41.36
10822.6 41.36
10826.9 41.36
10834.2 41.36
10838.1 41.36
10849 41.36
10856.6 41.36
10860.4 41.36
10871.4 41.36
10889.7 41.57
10894.8 41.36
10909.3 41.57
10921.5 41.57
10927.2 41.57
10938.1 41.57
10948 41.57
10960.6 41.57
10967.5 41.57
10985.1 41.57
10997.1 41.57
11011.4 41.57
11012.9 41.57
11024 41.57
11038.2 41.57
11050.6 41.57
11055.2 41.57
11068.9 41.57
11088.3 41.57
11095.3 41.57
11106.4 41.57
11113.1 41.57
11127.5 41.57
11139.7 41.57
11147 41.57
11158.2 41.57
11163.7 41.57
11176.4 41.57
11186.7 41.57
11193.9 41.57
11204.1 41.57
11209.1 41.57
11322.1 41.57
11376.2 41.57
11848.9 41.57
12112.2 41.57
12206.1 41.57
12235.1 41.36
12255.7 41.36
12280 41.36
12302.7 41.57
12327.7 41.57
12333.5 41.57
12349.5 41.57
12367.4 41.36
12382.5 41.36
12397.8 41.36
12410.6 41.57
12416.2 41.57
12432.6 41.57
12450.8 41.57
12463.9 41.36
12478.1 41.36
12491.9 41.57
12516 41.36
12533.6 41.36
12548 41.36
12561.9 41.36
12575.3 41.36
12585.9 41.36
12598.3 41.57
12612.1 41.36
12627.1 41.36
12638.3 41.36
12652.5 41.36
12665.9 41.36
12679.2 41.36
12678.6 41.36
12698 41.36
12711.6 41.36
12720.6 41.36
12734.4 41.36
12760.9 41.36
12767.6 41.36
12785.4 41.36
12803 41.36
12814.4 41.36
12828.3 41.36
12839.6 41.36
12850.9 41.36
12858.2 41.36
12871.5 41.36
12884.9 41.36
12894.8 41.36
12907.4 41.36
12921.9 41.36
12935.2 41.36
12942 41.36
12955 41.36
12973.5 41.36
12990 41.36
12998.1 41.36
13010 41.36
13017.7 41.36
13023 41.36
13034.5 41.15
13046.5 41.15
13054 41.36
13058.9 41.36
13071 41.36
13081.9 41.36
13089.8 41.36
13098.4 41.36
13104.8 41.36
13113 41.36
13119.7 41.36
13129 41.36
13136.5 41.36
13147.4 41.36
13154.8 41.36
13161.6 41.36
13168.8 41.36
13179.3 41.36
13205.4 41.36
13217.2 41.36
13223.4 41.36
13229.9 41.36
13241.5 41.36
13253 41.36
13256.8 41.36
13263 41.36
13267.5 41.36
13276.9 41.36
13284.3 41.36
13289.5 41.36
13294.5 41.36
13304.9 41.36
13313.5 41.36
13324.1 41.36
13329.7 41.36
13335.8 41.36
13352.9 41.36
13361.8 41.36
13368.7 41.36
13377.4 41.36
13388.3 41.36
13401.9 41.36
13408.4 41.36
13425.1 41.36
13444.9 41.15
13466.4 41.15
13474.1 41.36
13483.7 41.15
13489.4 41.36
13500.1 41.36
13508.3 41.36
13513.8 41.15
13521.4 41.36
13532.2 41.15
13540.2 41.36
13550.6 41.15
13556.1 41.15
13561.9 41.15
13572.4 41.15
13576.9 41.15
13581.3 41.15
13584.6 41.15
13596.1 41.15
13600.4 41.15
13610.9 41.15
13621 41.15
13625.6 41.15
13636.5 41.15
13641.3 41.15
13646 41.15
13656.2 41.15
13663.8 41.15
13672.4 41.15
13681 41.15
13686.4 41.15
13699 41.15
13707.7 41.15
13713.1 41.15
13721.9 41.15
13727.8 41.15
13736.4 41.15
13747.8 41.15
13753.2 41.15
13756.5 41.15
13761.7 41.15
13772.9 41.15
13779.5 41.15
13783.2 41.15
13785.7 41.15
13795.5 41.15
13802 41.15
13811.2 41.15
13813.6 40.94
13826.7 41.15
13834.6 41.15
13843.9 41.15
13854.4 41.15
13870.6 41.15
13891.9 41.15
13898.5 41.15
13902.8 40.94
13909.7 40.94
13919.1 41.15
13939 41.15
13954.7 41.15
13975.6 41.15
14001.6 41.15
14019.6 41.15
14026.7 41.15
14038.5 41.15
14051 41.15
14065.3 41.15
14076.9 41.15
14083.5 41.15
14095.9 41.15
14109 41.15
14120.1 41.15
14134.1 41.15
14156.3 41.15
14172.9 41.15
14188.9 41.15
14199.2 41.15
14210.1 41.15
14224.6 41.15
14235.8 41.15
14258.3 41.15
14274.3 41.15
14278.4 41.15
14284.8 41.15
14296.3 41.15
14317.3 41.15
14333.1 41.15
14348.3 41.15
14364.3 41.15
14372.2 41.15
14386.5 41.15
14403.2 41.15
14418.3 41.15
14431.9 41.15
14444.6 41.15
14447.7 41.15
14459.4 41.15
14474.5 41.15
14499.2 41.15
14503.9 41.15
14523.2 41.15
14538.7 40.94
14554.4 40.94
14571 41.15
14577.2 41.15
14589 41.15
14604.3 40.94
14630.8 41.15
14648.6 41.15
14659.3 40.94
14679.2 40.94
14684.3 41.15
14699.4 40.94
14705.6 40.94
14716.6 41.15
14729.1 41.15
14739.2 41.15
14745.7 41.15
14759.5 41.15
14775.9 41.15
14789.7 41.15
14798.7 40.94
14806 40.94
14811.8 40.94
14822.7 40.94
14833.1 40.94
14839.4 40.94
14844.4 40.94
14852.4 41.15
14859.9 40.94
15324 40.94
15592.5 40.94
15621.8 40.94
15651.3 40.94
15687.4 40.94
15708.8 40.94
15732.5 40.94
15755.9 40.94
15773.1 40.94
15810 40.94
15825.5 40.94
15842.2 40.73
15856.8 40.73
15880.6 40.73
15888.3 40.73
15905.2 40.73
15923.2 40.73
15941.6 40.73
15966.1 40.94
15988.5 40.73
16015 40.73
16033.8 40.73
16053.1 40.94
16072.8 40.73
16086.6 40.73
16096.3 40.94
16112.3 40.94
16129.9 40.94
16145.8 40.94
16156.9 40.94
16167.7 40.94
16190.6 40.94
16202 40.73
16212.5 40.94
16221.6 40.94
16231.9 40.94
16253.7 40.73
16264.6 40.73
16274.8 40.94
16290.6 40.94
16308.3 40.94
16317.3 40.94
16329.1 40.94
16344.6 40.94
16354.8 40.94
16375.2 40.73
16392.3 40.94
16398.7 40.94
16409.9 40.94
16424.9 40.73
16434.1 40.73
16445.5 40.94
16454.9 40.94
16459.7 40.94
16472.2 40.73
16479.3 40.73
16492.6 40.73
16498.2 40.73
16509.1 40.73
16521.1 40.73
16528.8 40.73
16541.2 40.73
16551 40.73
16564.6 40.73
16570.2 40.73
16582.4 40.73
16590.5 40.73
16604.5 40.73
16616.6 40.73
16623 40.73
16630.3 40.73
16642.7 40.73
16656.3 40.73
16668.6 40.73
16671.7 40.73
16676 40.73
16690.6 40.73
16699.7 40.73
16706.6 40.73
16716.6 40.73
16725.5 40.73
16739.7 40.73
16747.2 40.73
16754.9 40.73
16761.9 40.73
16776.6 40.73
16782.4 40.73
16798.1 40.73
16806.2 40.73
16817.9 40.52
16840.5 40.52
16842.1 40.52
16855 40.73
16856 40.73
16871.1 40.52
16878.6 40.52
16888.9 40.52
16895.7 40.52
16903.9 40.52
16916.7 40.52
16924.5 40.52
16932.7 40.52
16942.1 40.52
16955.6 40.52
16963.1 40.52
16970.4 40.52
16977.4 40.52
16985.8 40.52
16996.1 40.31
17004.2 40.52
17012.8 40.31
17019.4 40.52
17029.8 40.31
17036 40.31
17052.2 40.31
17067.6 40.31
17070.9 40.52
17084.2 40.52
17091.2 40.31
17101.8 40.31
17111.6 40.52
17917.1 40.52
17954.6 40.52
17973 40.52
17997.8 40.52
18022.8 40.52
18050.6 40.52
18071.3 40.52
18087.7 40.31
18105.3 40.31
18136.3 40.31
18148.7 40.31
18163.3 40.31
18177.1 40.52
18192.8 40.31
18214.5 40.31
18224.2 40.31
18246.2 40.31
18263.7 40.31
18285.6 40.31
18295.3 40.31
18308 40.31
18322.1 40.31
18328.7 40.31
18353.9 40.31
18368.3 40.31
18377.2 40.31
18388.9 40.31
18403 40.31
18429.5 40.31
18447 40.31
18458.1 40.31
18470.9 40.31
18497.4 40.31
18516.7 40.31
18531 40.31
18546.2 40.31
18570 40.31
18586.2 40.31
18598.6 40.31
18616.3 40.31
18636 40.31
18659.7 40.31
18674.3 40.31
18691.3 40.31
18719 40.1
18753.5 39.89
18779.2 40.31
18804.9 40.1
18822.4 40.1
18834.8 40.1
18858.4 40.31
18867.2 40.31
18878 40.1
18890.7 40.1
18906.2 40.1
18920 40.1
18931 40.1
18940.9 40.1
18949.7 40.1
18966.6 40.1
18974.5 40.1
18980.4 40.1
19012.2 40.1
19060.1 40.1
19087 40.1
19107.7 40.1
19120 40.1
19127.7 40.1
19144.1 40.1
19148 40.1
19156.6 40.1
19166.5 40.1
19178.2 40.1
19187.6 40.1
19198.1 40.1
19207.5 40.1
19215.3 39.89
19227.2 39.89
19237.4 39.89
19244.2 39.89
19253.9 39.89
19265.1 39.89
19274.3 39.89
19282.1 39.89
19291 39.89
19300.8 39.89
19308.7 39.68
19316.2 39.89
19321.2 39.89
19334.9 39.89
19341.9 39.89
19350.4 39.89
19358.2 39.89
19364.4 39.89
19373.8 39.89
19718.9 39.89
19916 39.89
20055.7 39.89
20132.1 39.89
20174.5 39.89
20195.8 39.89
20205.5 39.89
20217.5 39.89
20233.2 39.89
20252.2 39.89
20269.1 39.89
20283.3 39.89
20293.1 39.89
20312.1 39.89
20324.9 39.89
20337.5 39.89
20351.6 39.89
20360.4 39.89
20369.5 39.89
20383.6 39.89
20399.3 39.89
20410 39.89
20426 39.68
20445 39.89
20460.8 39.89
20469.6 39.89
20484.9 39.68
20502.1 39.89
20515.1 39.68
20525.6 39.68
20534.6 39.89
20549.6 39.68
20559.9 39.89
20570.8 39.68
20579.6 39.68
20593.2 39.68
20608.4 39.68
20615.5 39.68
20624.5 39.68
20632.3 39.68
20642.5 39.68
20651.9 39.68
20659.8 39.68
20667.7 39.68
20674.7 39.68
20685.8 39.68
20695.9 39.68
20701.1 39.68
20708.1 39.68
20718.8 39.68
20725.7 39.68
20734.8 39.68
20740.5 39.68
20744.6 39.68
20755.6 39.68
20761.6 39.68
20767.1 39.68
20776.1 39.68
20787.5 39.68
20795.2 39.68
20799.4 39.48
20810.5 39.68
20818.2 39.68
20828.7 39.68
20839.4 39.68
20846.7 39.68
20856.2 39.68
20866.9 39.68
20924.5 39.68
21202.2 39.68
21403.2 39.68
21483.7 39.68
21549.4 39.68
21562.9 39.48
21581.7 39.68
21596 39.68
21620.1 39.48
21634.3 39.48
21637.8 39.48
21651.2 39.48
21669 39.48
21689.9 39.48
21702.3 39.48
21716.2 39.48
21725.3 39.48
21747.6 39.48
21763.9 39.68
21775.6 39.68
21784.5 39.48
21808.3 39.48
21832.2 39.48
21849.7 39.48
21867.2 39.68
21883.5 39.68
21914.1 39.68
21924.8 39.68
21939.6 39.68
21962.4 39.68
21976.4 39.68
21991.5 39.68
22006 39.48
22012.6 39.48
22034.3 39.68
22058.7 39.68
22072.4 39.48
22089.6 39.68
22101.3 39.27
22111.8 39.68
22130.6 39.68
22147 39.68
22159.7 39.48
22174.2 39.68
22186.9 39.68
22196.7 39.48
22209.4 39.68
22216.3 39.68
22223.6 39.68
22236.4 39.48
22246.5 39.68
22255.3 39.48
22260.9 39.48
22271.5 39.68
22278 39.68
22282.6 39.48
22290.8 39.68
22297.8 39.68
22305.4 39.48
22313.1 39.48
22318.5 39.68
22324.6 39.68
22333.9 39.48
22338.4 39.68
22342.5 39.48
22349.5 39.48
22354.6 39.48
22363.9 39.48
22370.4 39.68
22378 39.48
22370.1 39.48
22654.6 39.48
22791.2 39.68
22810.2 39.48
22828.1 39.48
22893.1 39.48
22919.5 39.48
22929.8 39.68
22939.4 39.48
22947.5 39.68
22995.4 39.48
23012.6 39.48
23025.7 39.48
23054.9 39.48
23087.4 39.48
23114.4 39.48
23127.9 39.48
23153.8 39.48
23171.1 39.48
23191.6 39.48
23213.4 39.48
23223.3 39.68
23232.5 39.48
23244.8 39.48
23265.7 39.68
23284.1 39.68
23307.8 39.68
23325.8 39.48
23355.8 39.68
23376.1 39.68
23383.3 39.48
23393.3 39.48
23410.2 39.48
23443 39.48
23452.2 39.48
23462.4 39.48
23471.7 39.48
23487.2 39.27
23501.6 39.48
23524.9 39.48
23549.5 39.48
23563.3 39.27
23552.7 39.48
};
\end{axis}

\node at ({$(current bounding box.south west)!0.05!(current bounding box.south east)$}|-{$(current bounding box.south west)!0.95!(current bounding box.north west)$})[
  scale=0.8,
  anchor=north west,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{\bfseries A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the long data.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to add `scaled x ticks=false` to the options of the `axis` environment. To avoid having to manually edit the code after it was generated, you can tell `matplotlib2tikz` to add it, with the `extra_axis_parameters` key for `tikz_save`. It takes a set of options as the value, e.g.

```
tikz_save( 'myfile.tikz', extra_axis_parameters={'scaled x ticks=false'})
```

If I add `scaled x ticks=false` to your code, I get this:

[image]